# Is there a simple way to alphabetize a String Enumeration in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, enumeration

Just as the title says.

I tried messing around a bit with Collections.sort() on a List[] and the .sort() function of an ArrayList but I was never able to parse it back to an Enumeration.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's some pseduocode and further explanation. My goal is to take the keys() from a Hashtable and do complex operations involving each one, alphabetically.

My current process is:

1. Take a hash table I'm given
2. Form an enumeration from the ht
3. Run a while loop until the enumeration is empty

So the code is like this:

```
public void processData(Hashtable<String,GenericClass> htData)
{
    Enumeration<String> enData = htData.keys();

    while(enData.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String current = enData.nextElement();

        /*
         * DO COMPLEX PROCESS
         */
    }
}
```

The problem, is that the data in the enumeration has to be alphabetical (that is, the "complex process" must be done on each key in alphabetical order). Any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Err, Collections.sort() takes a List as a parameter, not a List[]. And ArrayList does not have a sort() method. You might want to rephrase your question.

Comment: maybe post some pseudo code or something for clarity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a sorted list you can use

Collections.enumeration(myList)

to get it back to an enumeration... if I'm following you correctly..

EDIT:

You can do this...

```
List l = new ArrayList(ht.keySet());
Collections.sort(l)
```

Comment: With my update in mind, I don't think there's a way to get the keys from the HT without using an Enumeration (the only HT method that really works is keys(), which returns an Enum)

Comment: You just missed the keySet() method... that'll give you something easier to work with... quick demo in my edited answer

Comment: Great, thanks! I used yours (and KLE's for-loop) to go though each item.

Comment: List list = new ArrayList(htData.keySet());
  Collections.sort(list);
  
  for(Object s : list)
  {
   System.out.println(s.toString());
  }

Answer (score 2):

If you need to iterate over the items in order of their keys, maybe it's better to use a [`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of a `Hashtable`. Its `keySet` method will return the keys in order.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately though, the Hashtable is a prereq.

Comment: In that case, use danb's solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about storing your keys in an ArrayList to sort them?

```
    List<String> list = // create from htData.keys()
    Collections.sort(list);
    for(String s : list) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
Enumeration<String> enumeration = dictionary.keys(); // unsorted enumeration        
List list= Collections.list(enumeration); // create list from enumeration 
Collections.sort(list);
enumeration = Collections.enumeration(list);
```